# Problema con converrsión de archivos de texto de Linux a AIX

Tags: linux, sed

mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo un archivo de texto en Linux, el cual, al ser abierto en un servidor AIX lo que en Linux se mostraba de la siguiente manera.

```
Linea1
linea2
Linea3
```

En AIX se muestra de la siguiente manera

```
Linea1Linea2Linea3
```

Quisiera saber si en AIX el caracter de fin de línea  de Linux (LF ó \n) es distinto o simplemente AIX no reconoce el fin de linea de Linux.¿Donde lo configuro?

Debo acotar que use un pequeño script en sed el cual convierte un archivo de formato Windows a Linux CRLF a LF, supongo que debo hacer un script parecido para convertir de LF a lo que sea que usa AIX, solo que ¿cual es el caracter de fin de linea en AIX?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Con qué editor lo abrías en linux? Con qué editor lo abres en AIX? Corre `locale` en cada entorno y trae la salida para ver qué sale en `LC_CTYPE=`

Comment: Por las dudas: Los Unixes usan `\n` == `ascii(10)` y por cierto tienes las herramients `dos2unix` o `unix2dos` para hacer justamente estas conversiones

Comment: En los servidores corri locale, este es el resultado

Comment: Servidor Linux ~]$ locale

LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"


Servidor AIX/ locale
LC_CTYPE="en_US"